# Is a String generic parameter treated as a value-type or reference-type?

Tags: c#, generics

From the [MSDN Generics in the Run Time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4a6ta2h.aspx) document I note:

> When a generic type is first constructed with a value type as a parameter, the runtime creates a specialized generic type with the supplied parameter or parameters substituted in the appropriate locations in the MSIL. Specialized generic types are created one time for each unique value type that is used as a parameter.

and

> Generics work somewhat differently for reference types. The first time a generic type is constructed with any reference type, the runtime creates a specialized generic type with object references substituted for the parameters in the MSIL. Then, every time that a constructed type is instantiated with a reference type as its parameter, regardless of what type it is, the runtime reuses the previously created specialized version of the generic type. This is possible because all references are the same size.

Am I correct to infer from this that, although the **string** data-type possesses value-type semantics in both C# and the CLR, a generic type instantiated with a **string** type parameter will use the same specialized generic type as the other reference types, rather than having its own as other value-type would? Has this behaviour, either way, been the same since V2 when generics were introduced?

Comment: Strings are reference types. That's all that matters.

Comment: Uhm, [strings are reference types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx), so they never posess “value-type semantics”.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`string` is a reference type in every way. It has ["value-type semantics"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_semantics) in the Wikipedia sense, but that doesn't make it a value type in the terminology used in MSDN. In the common CLR and C# terminology which divides all non-pointer types into "reference types" or "value types", a string is definitely a reference type. Note that you can easily build your own reference type with value semantics too - but it will still be a reference type in every way that the specifications care.

Comment: Doesn't the **Equals** operation on **String** provide value-type semantics also? That is what I am trying to preserve in the Maybe monad.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Well, it allows distinct instances to be equal... but any class can do that. It's not like that's restricted to value types. (I'll mention it in the answer though.)

Comment: Isn't that the definition of value-type semantics? That contents rather than storage location are compared? I know that it is never a **struct**.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: In the context of talking about C# and the CLR, "value type" has a very specific meaning in terms of various aspects of behaviour. Specifically, I'd start with "is the value of a variable of this type a reference to an object, or is it the data itself" - and in the case of `string`, the value of a variable is definitely a reference. This struct/class distinction is the one that the JIT cares about.

Comment: I took such care in my terminology, yet everyone assumes I am an idiot: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_semantics

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: But you decided to use terminology which is out of the context of the documentation you were quoting. No-one is assuming you are an idiot - just that you weren't considering the context. The documentation you quoted didn't talk about "value-type semantics" - it talked about value types, and in the context of .NET that has a very clear meaning which is not the same thing at all.

Comment: (Having said that, I'll clarify my answer.)